# Modifying a field in a data object is resulting in Unrecognized field exception

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, jax-rs, restlet

I have the following very simple POJO object

**Working Version**

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement 
public class Employee {
    long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long l) {
        this.id = l;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**JSON request body that i used**

{"id":"23", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Smith"}

**Modified Version which is resulting in Unrecognized Field**

```
package com.example.model;


public class Employee {
    long id;
    **String firstEmpName;**  // Resulting in unrecognized Field
    **String lastEmpName;**   // Resulting in Unrecognized Field

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long l) {
        this.id = l;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstEmpName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstEmpName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastEmpName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastEmpName = lastName;
    }
}
```

After changing the first name and last name to firstEmpName and lastEmpName, i tried to post the below request body

**JSON request body that i used**

{"id":"23", "firstEmpName":"John", "lastEmpName":"Smith"}

**Exception i got**

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "firstEmpName" (Class com.example.model.Employee), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.restlet.engine.io.UnclosableInputStream@2275a30f; line: 1, column: 29] (through reference chain: com.example.model.Employee["firstEmpName"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
```

Rest of the sample application is as follows:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

// Create a router Restlet that routes each call to a
    // new instance of HelloWorldResource.
    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    // Defines only one route
    router.attach("/employees/{id}", SampleAppRestlet_ServerServlet.class);


    return router;
}




      public class SampleAppRestlet_ServerServlet extends ServerResource {
         @Get
        public Employee getEmployee(){

                Employee m = new Employee();
                m.setFirstName("John");
                m.setLastName("Smith");
                m.setId(23);

                return m;

        }
    }
```

Everytime i change a field name, do i need to do something for that field to be recognized.

I also tried using Jax-rs instead of Restlet, i still see the same problem.

So to summarize the problem that i am having, whatever the pojo that i create in the first time is what remains and is working. If i changing any fields in the POJO like that of above, for example from firstName to firstEmpName, then i get the above exception. I tried to clean the classes, restarted the server. Removed local_db.bin and even changed the Pojo class name to a different and tried but still it is not working. BTW, i am using Google App engine. The restlet sdk i used was the GAE edition of Restlet sdk. Also i tried with JAX-RS. I resolved the library conflicts and everything works the first time i try and if i change the field names, then in the case JAX-RS, it silently ignores those fields whose names have been changed.

Any guess or thoughts or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: When you ask a question on StackOverflow, please post the version of the code that is NOT working, not the code as it USED to be when it was working. Well, you can post both versions, but the latter is not as important as the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties in Java Beans are defined by the method names, not the field names. So you should rename the `get` and `set` methods to match the field names.